# Prism syntax high-lighting not working in Gatsby markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby, bulma

My syntax highlighting isn't working properly. The numbered lines show up, and the background works, but the syntax is not being highlighted.

I am also using Bulma if that makes a difference. I don't know if styles are overriding each other?

Here's a screen shot of what I see on my Gatsby blog:

[image: code]

gatsby-browser:

`require('prismjs/themes/prism.css');
require('prismjs/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.css');`

Here are my plugins

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
            options: {
              classPrefix: 'language-',

              inlineCodeMarker: null,

              aliases: { sh: 'bash', js: 'javascript' },

              showLineNumbers: true,

              noInlineHighlight: false,

              languageExtensions: [
                {
                  language: 'superscript',
                  extend: 'javascript',
                  definition: {
                    superscript_types: /(SuperType)/,
                  },
                  insertBefore: {
                    function: {
                      superscript_keywords: /(superif|superelse)/,
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
              // Customize the prompt used in shell output
              // Values below are default
              prompt: {
                user: 'root',
                host: 'localhost',
                global: false,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1200,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },

    // `gatsby-transformer-remark` -- this overrides previous config
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/mt.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
```

https://github.com/wbonneville/gatsby_blog here is my repo. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this work locally? I am having the same issue, I keep getting `warning unable to find prism language '.' for highlighting. applying generic code block` but all my code blocks are marked apart from the single line ones. Although my set up works locally just not in prod